# Local variables in parallel foreach loops c#

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel-processing

I had two nested `foreach` loops that need to run through a significant amount of data and calculation. Regular `foreach` loops took far too long (several hours).

So, I looked up ways to speed it up and found `Parallel.ForEach`. This is my first time dealing with parallelisation but the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) seem easy enough.

Below is my code currently, the problem with this is local variables (I think, at least). errors are added for nodes that work fine outside of the parallel loops.

```
Parallel.ForEach(allNodes, (startNode) =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(allNodes, (endNode) =>
    {
        if (startNode != endNode)
        {
            List<Geo_Model_Struct> route = pathfinder.getRouteOptimised(startNode, endNode);

            if (route.Count <= 0)
            {
                //failed to find route
                errors.Add(string.Format("Cound not find a route from {0} to {1}", startNode, endNode));
            }
            else
            {
                List<Geo_Model_Struct> accessibleRoute = accessiblePathfinder.getRouteOptimised(startNode, endNode);
                if (accessibleRoute.Count <= 0)
                {
                    //failed to find route
                    errors.Add(string.Format("Cound not find an accessible route from {0} to {1}", startNode, endNode));
                }
            }            
        }
        endCount++;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I: {0}/{1}\tJ: {2}/{3}", startCount, allNodes.Count - 1, endCount, allNodes.Count - 1);
    }
  );
    startCount++;
});
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the `route` local variable being altered when it shouldn't as nearly all checked routes fail. But I don't know how to reliably debug this kind of thing so any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I am testing all possible routes to make sure they all work. `route.Count` should be `> 0` for most tests. When using traditional `foreach` loops this is the case (e.g. 15 out of 500 times `route.Count <= 0` is `true`)

When using `Parallel.ForEach` `route.Count` is `0` most of the time (e.g. somewhere in the region of 494 out of 500 times) so very few actually pass the test and when looking at the errors produced most that fail in parallel, pass using the traditional `foreach`

**Solved**

I found a way to remove the need to get data from the database within the `getRouteOptimised` method. This fixed the issue. Still not sure exactly what it is about the db connection that caused the problem, but it works now.

Comment: Your problem is likely the count your keeping. Is that a locked int? If not it will need to be in order to work although keeping count inside a parallel loop is not the best idea most of the time. What's the goal of the count? Also is your error collection a thread safe collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I suspect the issue is with the pathfinder and accessiblepathfinder objects. They may not be thread safe. A *possible* way to circumvent this is to create those variables locally within the inner foreach loop.

```
if (startNode != endNode)
{
    // Create and Initialise pathfinder here
    MyPathFinderObject pathfinder = new MyPathFinderObject(<parameters>);
    List<Geo_Model_Struct> route = pathfinder.getRouteOptimised(startNode, endNode);

    if (route.Count <= 0)
        .../...
    else
    {                        
        // Create and Initialise accessiblePathfinder here
        MyAccessiblePathFinderObject accessiblePathfinder = new MyAccessiblePathFinderObject(<parameters>);
        List<Geo_Model_Struct> accessibleRoute = accessiblePathfinder.getRouteOptimised(startNode, endNode);
        .../...
    }            
}
```

However there is no guarantee that this will work.

[From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx):

> You must be extremely cautious when getting data from properties and methods. Large object models are known for sharing mutable state in unbelievably devious ways.